# r shiny using system command error

Tags: r, shell, unix, rstudio

When I am trying to use the below code in RStudio I am getting error.

Code:

```
system(paste("sshpass -v -f -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i '<Path>/id_rsa.ppk' -L 3306:localhost:3306 root@127.0.0.1 sleep 20"))
```

Warning:

```
running command 'sshpass -v -f -N -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i '<Path>/id_rsa.ppk' -L 3306:localhost:3306 root@127.0.0.1 sleep 20' had status 127
```

How can I resolve the above issue in R?

Comment: Please use formatting of code, edit your question!

Comment: `sshpass` is not a substitute for `ssh` -- read your `sshpass` and  `ssh` manual pages.